# How to calculate the contour integration?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I encountered some problems when I read the paper. The details are shown as follows.
\begin{equation}
pdf(I)=e^I \prod_{i=1}^n \left(-j a_i\right)\int \frac{dk}{2\pi}\frac{e^{jk\left(e^I-1\right)}}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(k-ja_i\right)} 
\tag{$1$}
\end{equation}
where $j^2=-1$.
Since the $a_i$ are all nonnegative and real, we can close the integration
contour in the upper half plane. (In the case where one or more
$a_i$ are precisely zero, a limit should be taken where they approach zero
from the positive side.) In addition, we see from (1) that in
the limit of a particular $a_i$ going to infinity $a_i \to \infty$, that term cancels, and the product is over the remaining $n-1$ degrees of freedom. In the
case where all of the $a_i$'s are different, this immediately yields
\begin{equation}
pdf(I)=\left(\prod_{i=1}^n a_i\right)\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{f(a_i, I)}{a_i\prod\limits_{m \neq i}\left(a_m-a_i\right)}\tag{$2$}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
f\left(a, I\right)=a \exp\left(I-a\left(e^I-1\right)\right)
\end{equation}

Now, I want to know how to derive the formula (2) from (1). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: There is more than one paper.

Comment: I have no idea about the solution of the formula (1).

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler articles are notoriously difficult for non-native English speakers (as I'm sure you know). He read *a* paper.

Comment: Have you attempted to use the residue theorem, and if so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: @NikWeaver Whether *a* or *the* (not my intended point, sorry if it came across that way), the OP ought to help helpers by spelling out *which* paper.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler of course, I agree.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved this problem with residue theorem.